# Failed to use ffmpeg to join frames into video

Tags: shell, video, ffmpeg, frames

**Hello there,**

I want to join frames into an mp4 video using ffmpeg. The frames are in a folder named:

```
img_001.jpg
img_002.jpg
img_003.jpg
...
```

Now I found following command here:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -start_number 2 -i img_%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

My only problem is that it makes my frames 2 seconds long in the final video. But instead, I want to have an output video that runs with 30fps and every singe frame is one separate image from my folder, so it shouldn't replicate frames. I don't know how to use ffmpeg so can somebody help me to achieve this?

*Thanks for the answers in advance!*

Comment: See first answer at duplicate link. Use `-framerate 30`. `-r` is optional if output rate is same.